# Pointing links within a view to correct page

Tags: views, navigation, path-aliases

Hi guys I am having an issue with trying to get the links contained within a View to point to the correct pages of my site.

The links can be seen here: [Modules Page](http://jciadt.com/cms/ca2/modules-page)

Currently when the user selects a link they are taking to a page like this: (if you choose "Advanced Javascript" link)

[Advanced Javascript](http://jciadt.com/cms/ca2/node/12)

However I want them to be directed to this page: (Which is also another View)

[Ajstest](http://jciadt.com/cms/ca2/ajstest)

I am at a loss as to how to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to tell us how you currently build the links, and also what kind of page the target page is. It looks like a views page, but is this build?

Comment: Yes this page is built already, it is a views page. As for constructing the links, I've just used the default that views provides when constructing a page. I have it set to unformatted list and the list it displays are links to the pages of my site.

Comment: It's link to nodes on your site. If those nodes are not the pages that you want to link, then you should build your view differently. Maybe you should use a view that lists the taxonomy terms, just like the sidebar block (Modules) does.